# Rollback transaction não funciona como esperado

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-basic-6

Estive recentemente implementando uma sequencia de requisições no Visual Basics, e gostaria de dar um rollback quando alguma falhar. Por tanto fiz da seguinte forma:

```
Public Class DAO
    Dim connection As New MysqlConnection
    Dim command As New MySqlCommand
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
    Dim transaction As MySqlTransaction

    Public Sub New()
        connection = New MySqlConnection(`MYDATA_FROM_DATABASE`)
        connection.Open()
        transaction = connection.BeginTransaction
        command.Connection = connection
        command.Transaction = transaction
    End Sub

    Public Sub Rollback()
        Try
            transaction.Rollback()
            connection.Close()
        Catch
        EndTry
    End Sub

    Public Sub Close()
        Try
            transaction.Commit()
            connection.Close()
        Catch
        EndTry
    End Sub
End Class
```

E com isso eu crio outras classes DAOS, herdando dessa aí. As outras classes possuem outros metodos, exemplo:

```
Public Class UsuarioDAO
    Inherits DAO

    Public Function Insere(nome As String) As Boolean
        Try
            command.commandText = "INSERT INTO Usuario(Nome) VALUES('" & nome & "')"
            command.ExecuteNonQuery
            Return True
        Catch
            Return False
        End Try
    End Function 
End Class
```

E, por exemplo, desejo inserir 3 usuários, e se der erro desfaço tudo:

Suponto um método em um outro local qualquer do código

```
Public Sub Insere3Usuarios
    Dim UsuarioDAO As New UsuarioDAO
    If UsuarioDAO.Insere("USUARIO_1") And UsuarioDAO.Insere("USUARIO_2") And UsuarioDAO.Insere("USUARIO_3") Then
        UsuarioDAO.Close()
    Else
        UsuarioDAO.Rollback()
    End If
End Sub
```

Após chamar esse metodo `Insere3Usuarios`, posso forçar o rollback, chamando em vez de `Close()`, o método `Rollback()` da classe DAO, mesmo quando for dar sucesso.

E fazendo o teste não obtenho sucesso no Rollback. Alguém sabe me dar uma luz do porquê?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta faltando dar o Commit na função Insere apos a linha:

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery
```

Pois sem o commit, não há nada para "Reverter" com o Rollback.

Comment: Entao eu devo dar o commit após cada operação, depois fazer o `rollback`? E aquele commit na função `Close` não deveria existir?

Comment: Sim, depois da linha comand.ExecuteNonQuery, coloque: transaction.Commit();